# How to send an SMS text message that includes a hyperlink to a web page

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, sms

I'm using VB.NET 2017 Pro to send SMS text messages out through SendGrid.
Works great.
Now I want to embed in the message a hyperlink to my web page.
It shows just the prompt ok, without showing the: PROMPT
But the prompt is not a hyperlink (ie. not highlighted).

I'm sending to @vtext.com     ie. Verizon

Here is what's sent:

```
Touch: <a href="http://yadayada/Default.aspx?O=IFF&ROA=9252003200@vtext.com&EPI=&SP=1111111111@gmail.com">ACCEPT FRIEND</a>
```

Mobile displays   "Touch: ACCEPT FRIEND" which is not a hyperlink

Comment: Well its a *text* message not an *HTML* message, most handsets will convert `http://xxx` into a link automatically, and you can hide the querystring with a token/rewrite you generate then lookup (http://yadayada/xyz123).  Your only other alternative is a WAP Push instead of an SMS.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm planning to try...can't think of anything else.